# How do you allow the WKWebView to accept redirect url

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Having some trouble redirecting a user to a link from a WKWebView.

User is essentially meant to be authenticating on a website using WKWebView, the website checks the authentication which in turn redirects the user back to our app.

My initial thought is that there is some sort of restriction to allow the user to exit the app during the redirecting process. Which is why I implemented WKNavigationDelegate and saw that when we try authenticating the code below didReceive challenge runs through the second if case - which I only assume that its a good thing. Though the app does not get redirected.

Below is the code I have.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewViewController: UIViewController, WKUIDelegate,       WKNavigationDelegate {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        if let url = URL(string: "SomeUrl") {
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            webView.load(request)
        }
    }

    override func loadView() {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        if let URL = webView.request?.url {
            OAuthHelper.oAuthManager.processOAuthStep1Response(url: URL)
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {

    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        if challenge.previousFailureCount > 0 {
            completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
        } else if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust {
            completionHandler(Foundation.URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
        } else {
            print("unknown state. error: \(challenge.error)")
            // do something w/ completionHandler here
        }
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if (navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated){
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
        } else {
            decisionHandler(.allow)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not fully understand the problem. If the question is that if you want the user to redirect from Webview to Native App, then you do have different options. I will be providing the options. Let me know if this is you are looking at.

1. Use **WKURLSchemeHandler** to handle the custom URLs. Read my article about this. https://medium.com/@kumarreddy_b/custom-scheme-handling-in-uiwebview-wkwebview-bbeb2f3f6cc1. https://github.com/BKRApps/KRWebView
2. you will be getting the urls in **func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)**, here you can intercept the URL and then use your URL scheme to get into the native app. Use OpenUrl to do this. But this is deprecated.